# Understanding the usage of "," before "which" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I have difficulty in understanding which of the following is correct:

> Team cannot be fully discussed without considering two
>   factors **which** are teams’ makeup and teams’ performance.

or

> Team cannot be fully discussed without considering two
>   factors **, which** are teams’ makeup and teams’ performance.

Comment: There are *numerous* Qs in here which already address the use or absence of a comma before "which".

Answer (score 0):

The statement is better with the comma and might well be wrong without it.

However, the statement is also either badly contrived or the result of bad teaching and either way contains mistakes quite aside from the question.

If the subject is ’team’, the makeup and performance are not ‘teams’ ’ but ’team’s ’.

Before that, ‘Team cannot…’ anything cannot be complete.

‘A (or the) team’ perhaps.

‘The concept of teams / a team’ perhaps but never just ‘team…’